# ¿Cómo hacer que en el JDataChooser se vean los dias en el calendario?

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo un proyecto en Java Swing y quiero agregar un campo de fecha para mi base de datos, pero resulta que al dar click en el componente del calendario si muestra el calendario y el problema reside en que no se ve como esperaba ya que no se miran los días del mes sino puros cuadritos con puntos suspensivos en lugar del número del día

este es mi código

```
package agenciaviajes;

import static agenciaviajes.main_window.getConection;
import datechooser.beans.DateChooserCombo;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;


public class frame_clientes extends javax.swing.JFrame{
String ImagePath = null;

public frame_clientes() {
    initComponents();
}

public ImageIcon ResizeImage(String imagePath, byte[] pic){
    ImageIcon imagen = null;

    if(!imagePath.equals("")){
        imagen = new ImageIcon(imagePath);
    }else{
        imagen = new ImageIcon(pic);

    }

    Image img = imagen.getImage();
    Image img2 = img.getScaledInstance(lbl_foto.getWidth(), lbl_foto.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(img2);


    return image;
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    dateChooserDialog1 = new datechooser.beans.DateChooserDialog();
    dateChooserDialog2 = new datechooser.beans.DateChooserDialog();
    dateChooserDialog3 = new datechooser.beans.DateChooserDialog();
    dateChooserDialog4 = new datechooser.beans.DateChooserDialog();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    txt_nombre_cliente = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    txt_apellidos_cliente = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    txt_id_cliente = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    txt_email = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    txt_domicilio = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    txt_telefono = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    btn_actualizarc = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btn_eliminarc = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btn_resetc = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btn_guardarc = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    txa_comentarios = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    lbl_foto = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    btn_chooseImage = new javax.swing.JButton();
    txt_fechanaci = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    fecha_naci = new datechooser.beans.DateChooserCombo();
    jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
    setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1830, 800));
    getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

    jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));
    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Administracion de clientes", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.TOP, new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24))); // NOI18N
    jPanel1.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1800, 800));
    jPanel1.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1800, 800));
    jPanel1.setOpaque(false);

    jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Formulario clientes", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.LEFT, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.TOP, new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18))); // NOI18N
    jPanel2.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1600, 800));
    jPanel2.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(600, 800));

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("NOMBE");

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setText("TELEFONO");

    jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel3.setText("FECHA DE NACIMIENTO");

    jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel4.setText("ID");

    jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel5.setText("APELLIDOS");

    jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel6.setText("COMENTARIOS");

    jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel7.setText("E-MAIL");

    txt_apellidos_cliente.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            txt_apellidos_clienteActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    txt_email.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            txt_emailActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    txt_domicilio.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            txt_domicilioActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    txt_telefono.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            txt_telefonoActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel8.setText("DOMICILIO");

    btn_actualizarc.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    btn_actualizarc.setText("Actualizar");

    btn_eliminarc.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    btn_eliminarc.setText("Eliminar");

    btn_resetc.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    btn_resetc.setText("Reset");

    btn_guardarc.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    btn_guardarc.setText("Guardar");
    btn_guardarc.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btn_guardarcActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    txa_comentarios.setColumns(20);
    txa_comentarios.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(txa_comentarios);

    lbl_foto.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 204));
    lbl_foto.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));

    btn_chooseImage.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    btn_chooseImage.setText("Foto");
    btn_chooseImage.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btn_chooseImageActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    txt_fechanaci.setText("dd/mm/yyyy");
    txt_fechanaci.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            txt_fechanaciActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 164, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 164, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 164, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 164, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(43, 43, 43)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(txt_apellidos_cliente)
                        .addComponent(txt_nombre_cliente)
                        .addComponent(txt_id_cliente)
                        .addComponent(txt_fechanaci, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 223, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGap(51, 51, 51)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 164, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 164, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addComponent(jLabel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 164, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 164, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(btn_guardarc)
                    .addGap(11, 11, 11)
                    .addComponent(btn_actualizarc)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(btn_eliminarc, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 91, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(btn_resetc, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 83, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(fecha_naci, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(txt_email)
                .addComponent(txt_telefono)
                .addComponent(txt_domicilio)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 223, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 90, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(lbl_foto, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 167, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(btn_chooseImage, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGap(32, 32, 32))
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(lbl_foto, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 131, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(btn_chooseImage, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(txt_telefono, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addComponent(txt_id_cliente, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(txt_nombre_cliente, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(txt_email, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(txt_domicilio, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addComponent(txt_apellidos_cliente))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 26, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 26, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(txt_fechanaci))
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(btn_eliminarc, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(btn_actualizarc, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(btn_resetc, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(btn_guardarc, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(fecha_naci, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 77, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jPanel3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));
    jPanel3.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Clientes", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.LEFT, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.TOP, new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 14))); // NOI18N

    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {

        },
        new String [] {
            "ID", "NOMBRE", "APELLIDOS", "FECHA NACIMIENTO", "TELEFONO", "E-MAIL", "DOMICILIO", "COMENTARIOS"
        }
    ));
    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTable1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
    jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
    jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 1255, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 295, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(69, 69, 69)
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addGap(0, 521, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 227, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 329, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 200, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    getContentPane().add(jPanel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 1300, 620));

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void txt_telefonoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                            

private void txt_domicilioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                             

private void txt_emailActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                         

private void txt_apellidos_clienteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                                     

private void txt_fechanaciActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                             

private void btn_chooseImageActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    JFileChooser filec = new JFileChooser();
    filec.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));

    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.images","jpg","png");
    filec.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
    int result = filec.showSaveDialog(null);
    if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        File selectedFile = filec.getSelectedFile();
        String path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
        lbl_foto.setIcon(ResizeImage(path, null));
        ImagePath = path;
    }else{
        System.out.println("No hay imagen seleccionada");
    }


}                                               
public boolean chekFields(){
    if(txt_nombre_cliente.equals("")||
       txt_apellidos_cliente.equals("")||
       txt_fechanaci.equals("")||
       txt_domicilio.equals("")||
       txt_email.equals("")||
       txt_telefono.equals("")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Campos vacios");
        return false;
    }else{
    return true;
    }
}

private void btn_guardarcActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    Connection con = null;
    fecha_naci = new DateChooserCombo();
    fecha_naci.setVisible(true);
    if(chekFields() && !ImagePath.equals("")){
        con = getConection();

        try{
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO cliente(nombres,apellidos,fecha_naci,telefono,email,domicilio,comentarios,foto)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            ps.setString(1, txt_nombre_cliente.getText());
            ps.setString(2, txt_apellidos_cliente.getText());

            ps.setString(3, txt_fechanaci.getText());
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
            String fecha = df.format(txt_fechanaci.getDate());
           ps.setString(3, fecha);

            //ps.setDate(3, Date.valueOf(txt_fechanaci.getText()));
            ps.setString(4, txt_telefono.getText());
            ps.setString(5, txt_email.getText());
            ps.setString(6, txt_domicilio.getText());
            ps.setString(7, txa_comentarios.getText());

            InputStream img = new FileInputStream(new File(ImagePath));
            ps.setBlob(8, img);

            ps.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Datos insertados con éxito");
        }catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: "+ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println(""+ex.getStackTrace());
            System.out.println(""+ex.getMessage());
        }

    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los campos son requeridos");

    }
    System.out.println("nombre = " +txt_nombre_cliente.getText());
    System.out.println("ape = " +txt_apellidos_cliente.getText());
    System.out.println("fecha = " +txt_fechanaci.getText());
    System.out.println("tel = " +txt_telefono.getText());
    System.out.println("email = " +txt_email.getText());
    System.out.println("domi = " +txt_domicilio.getText());
    System.out.println("comen = " +txa_comentarios.getText());
    System.out.println("foto = " +ImagePath);
}                                            

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frame_clientes.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frame_clientes.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frame_clientes.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frame_clientes.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new frame_clientes().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify
```

}

[image: Formulario java swing]

[image: Calendario en blanco]

Answer (score 0):

El problema es la Libreria que estas usando para desplegar el Calendario.

estas usando `datechooser.beans.DateChooserCombo`, esta libreria es Open Source (**Pero no es parte de las librerias Swing de Java** y por tanto no es estandar) y esta en este GIT: [jdatechooser](https://github.com/vadimig/jdatechooser)

Sin embargo el ultimo commit fue en el 2014 y segun veo Tiene 2 Problemas reportados que Son presisamente el que haces la pregunta: [error reportado en GIT](https://github.com/vadimig/jdatechooser/issues/2)

para solucionarlo tienes 3 opciones: remover el codigo donde configura Nimbus como el Look & feel del applicativo

1. Cambiar el Look&Feel (eliminar el siguiente codigo):

   ```
   try {
       for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
           if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
               javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
               break;
           }
       }
   } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
   java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frame_clientes.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
   java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frame_clientes.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
   java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frame_clientes.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
   java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frame_clientes.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
   ```
2. usar JavaFX:

   [JavaFx Date Picker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/date-picker.htm)

   y usar componentes JavaFX de la mano con Swing:

   [Swing Y java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm)

   [ejemplo DatePicker en applicacion Swing](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2016/05/javafx-8-datepicker-swing-application.html)
3. revisar el codigo ( que puedes bajar de: [jdatechooser](https://github.com/vadimig/jdatechooser)) y buscar que debes cambiar para que el jdatechooser funcione como deseas.

   O en su defecto Usar otra Libreria Que este mas Al dia y sea funcional por Ejemplo: [LGoodDatePicker](https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker)